# MacOS and Kindle file Location Changed?

Tags: mac, file-conversion, kindle

MacOS Kindle version 1.12.0 no longer seems to keep downloaded books in the My Kindle Library location, no new files are showing up there. Does anyone know where they are being stored now? Without these files to find and remove the DRM for use on other non-kindle readers I'll probably just go back to finding my books on DRM free sites 8(

Comment: @Mark I believe that question is specific to the Mac App Store version of the Kindle app. The answer I posted below is accurate.

Comment: @tubedogg  I suspect a mix - I gave the default path and mentioned that it could be edited - from my wording I suspect it used not to be editable but now is - also whare is a non Mac store version?

Comment: @Mark The link in my answer is a non-MAS version.

Answer (score 3):

Using Kindle v1.17.0, Kindle content is stored in the location set under Kindle menu > Preferences > General tab > Content Folder. (The default appears to be ~/Documents/My Kindle Content.)

If you are using Kindle for Mac from the Mac App Store, it has not been updated in nearly a year, and you should switch to the version downloaded directly from Amazon.

You can download or update Kindle for Mac by getting it directly from this Amazon site: https://www.amazon.com/gp/kindle/mac/download. (Note that clicking that link will initiate the download.)